# Как проверить все ли столбцы SQL заполнены?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть таблица mysql с 50 столбцами.
Как проверить на PHP, что все столбцы заполнены?

Comment: Поставить в базе для столбцов ограничение `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Получить список записей с признаком, есть ли хотя бы в одном поле NULL:

```
SELECT id, 
       CONCAT(field1, 
              field2, 
           /* ..... , */
              field50) IS NULL record_contain_nulls 
FROM table
```

Получить список записей, где хотя бы в одном поле есть NULL:

```
SELECT id
FROM table
WHERE CONCAT(field1, 
             field2, 
          /* ..... , */
             field50) IS NULL
```

Просто проверить, есть ли в таблице хотя бы одна запись, где хотя бы в одном поле есть NULL:

```
SELECT MAX(CONCAT(field1, 
                  field2, 
               /* ..... , */
                  field50) IS NULL) table_contain_nulls 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Тут вариантов несколько, и всё зависит от того, зачем вам это нужно.

1.Можно, как уже написал @AntonShchyrov, при создании базы указывать значение столбца not null

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

И тогда нельзя будет добавить запись с пустым значением.

2.Можно перед отправкой запроса делать проверку

```
function sendMail($email,$name,$text){
    if ( !empty($email) || !empty($name) || !empty($text) ) {
        // отправляем письмо или что-то другое делаем и возвращаем true
        return true;
    } else {
        // если какое-то поле пустое - возвращаем ошибку или просто false
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Вариант не подходит, так как я допускаю наличие пустых столбцов. 2.Можно перед отправкой запроса делать проверку
Согласен, но если столбцов 50 или 100 - это неудобно.

Comment: @AntonBogomolov вручную конечно неудобно.. Можно создать коллекцию правил и проверять их через неё